# Repeated elements in regexes of literals with alternation in Perl 6

Tags: raku

What is the best way to treat repetitions in `regexes` like `abc | cde | abc | cde | cde | abc` or `<regex1> | <regex2> | <regex3> | <regex4> | <regex5> | <regex6>`, where many of `regexN` will be the same literals?

To explain what I mean, I'll give an example from German. Here is a sample `grammar` that can parse several Present tense verbal forms.

```perl6
grammar Verb {
    token TOP {
        <base>
        <ending>
    }
    token base {
        geh   |
        spiel |
        mach
    }
    token ending {
        e     |  # 1sg
        st    |  # 2sg
        t     |  # 3sg
        en    |  # 1pl
        t     |  # 2pl
        en       # 3pl
    }
}

my @verbs = <gehe spielst machen>;
for @verbs -> $verb {
  my $match = Verb.parse($verb);
  say $match;
}
```

Endings for 1pl and 3pl (`en`) are the same, but for the sake of clarity it's more convenient to put them both into the `token` (in my real-life data inflexional paradigms are much more complex, and it's easy to get lost). The `token ending` works as expected, but I understand that if I put `en` only once, the program would work a bit faster (I've made tests with `regexes` consisting of many such repeated elements, and yes, the performance suffers greatly). With my data, there are lots of such repetitions, so I wonder what is the best way to treat them?

Of course, I could put the endings in an `array` outside the `grammar`, make this array `.unique` and then just pass the values:

```perl6
my @endings = < ... >;
@endings .= unique;
...
token ending { @endings }
```

But taking data out of the `grammar` will make it less clear. Also, in some cases it might be necessary to make each ending a separate token (`token ending {<ending_1sg> | <ending_2sg> ... <ending_3pl>}`, which would be impossible if they are defined outside the `grammar`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, for the sake of clarity, you want to repeat regex terms with a comment that describes which notes it's a separate concept? Just comment the line out.

By the way, since empty regexes are ignored in this case, it's okay to begin the line with your branch operator, instead of putting it at the end. It makes things easier, especially when you need to add and remove lines. So I suggest something like this:

```
grammar Verb {
    # ...
    token ending {
        | e       # 1sg
        | st      # 2sg
        | t       # 3sg
        | en      # 1pl
        #| t       # 2pl
        #| en      # 3pl
    }
}
```

Because what you're writing is exclusively for the human, not for the parser. Now, if you wanted to use the different regexes to go into different parse matches so you could access the ending as either `$<_3sg>` or `$<_2p1>` (named regexes so both would succeed), you can't comment it out, and you're gonna have to force the computer to do the extra work. And obviously you'll need to use `:exhaustive` or `:overlap`. Instead, I would suggest you make a named regex that represents both 3sg and 2p1, and define it like I did above: write them both but comment one out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially for showing the possibility to put `|` before the 1st alternative!
I considered both solutions (commenting lines with duplicates or merging duplicates into one `token`). Both of them have certain drawbacks for me (continued in the next comment).

Comment: ① having dozens of different endings, it's very difficult to remember, which of them are unique and which are duplicate, and manually commenting/uncommenting many lines is inevitably prone to errors. ② If my conditions change slightly (say, I want to add or remove several endings, or to modify some of them), I'll have to check all of them, commenting/uncommenting the relevant lines. That's why I was thinking about something like `.unique`. It seems, the only solution is to give the computer extra work, which is not very exciting, since my textual corpora and number of `base`s are very large.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky It seems like you want a way to generate a grammar, or to generate parts of a grammar. That way you could write the generator in the way you understand best, and make changes in the generating code. Be warned, this is HARD! I read a blog post on this, but it's just a summary. The full implementation is harder. (But the author linked to an example module they wrote which you can download and look at.): https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2015/12/08/day-8-grammars-generating-grammars/

Comment: That's very interesting indeed! But alas, it certainly exceeds my present skills :) So (having this in mind for future) I'll stick to the 3 alternatives you've shown me (depending on the actual task): ① leaving some extra work for the computer, ② commenting the unwanted lines and ③ combining several identical endings into one `token`.

Comment: Another practical solution came to my mind. The problem can be split into two parts. ① Time-consuming filtering of the corpus. Here the endings can be passed from `@array.unique`, which can be even 'precompiled' to work faster. ② Parsing of the filtered forms, where we can leave all the duplicate endings in the `grammar`/`regex`, since the speed is not crucial here.